# jQuery Autogrow and Autosize - They're not applying to my input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

These are the two scripts I'm trying to use. I only need one to work, but right now I can't get either:

- [autogrow](http://plugins.jquery.com/autogrow/)
- [autosize](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/)

---

[image: File Structure]

In my head element, I called the scripts:

```
        <script src="js/jquery.autosize.js"></script>
        <script src="js/autogrow.js"></script>
```

This is the element I'm dealing with. It's not an option to assign the autoresize (below) by data-integer-question, or id.

```
<form method="post" action="submit.php" class="questionformcss">
<input type="text" name="username" class="questioninputcss" data-integer-question="863">    
</form>
```

At the bottom of my page, I used this jQuery to call them:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.questioninputcss').autogrow();
});
```

I also tried `autosize` instead of autogrow.

In neither case, does the form resize when text is added. And with autogrow, there's supposed to be an icon at the bottom right of the form that lets you resize it manually - that doesn't exist.

There are no errors in my console.

--

In autogrow's case, I also tried calling every script:

```
<script src="js/jquery.autosize.js"></script>
<script src="js/autogrow.jquery.json"></script>
<script src="js/autogrow.min"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above mentioned plugins work only for textarea auto increase. 
If you want to auto increase for input fields go with this plugin: 
https://github.com/MartinF/jQuery.Autosize.Input

Here is the working demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/silpa/mJMpw/832/)

```
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="Autosize" data-autosize-input='{ "space": 40 }' />
```

---

```
$(function() {
    $("input").autosizeInput();
});
```

Comment: Great! I set it to textarea and autogrow works. Thanks.